# Order: Fragment OPs guaranteed after vertex OPs? Logical & rasterization order seem to weak

Tags: vulkan

In my quest to fully understand synchronization, I've stumbled over different order guarantees. The strongest one I think is the rasterization order, which makes strong guarantees about the order of fragment operations for individual pixels.

A weaker and more general order is the logical order of the pipeline stages. To quote the bible:

> Pipeline stages that execute as a result of a command logically complete execution in a specific order, such that completion of a logically later pipeline stage must not happen-before completion of a logically earlier stage. [...] Similarly, initiation of a logically earlier pipeline stage must not happen-after initiation of a logically later pipeline stage.

That guarantee seems pretty weak as it seems to allow to run all pipeline stages at the same time as long as they start and end in the correct order.

That leads me to one consequence: Doesn't all this make it possible for the vertex stage to not be finished before the fragment stage starts? This is considering the case for a single triangle. Since I think thisis absolutely not what's happening (or possible), it would be nice to find out where the spec makes that guarantee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one problem with your thinking. Pipeline is not a Finite State Machine. They may look the same when expressed as diagram, but they are not the same. Pipeline stages do not "run", because they are not FSM states. Instead queue operations run **through** the pipeline (hence the name). In reality, one command can spawn multiple vertex shader invocations. Geometry shader can spawn multiple (or no) fragments shader invocations. Only thing that is guaranteed here is that things do not go against the pipeline direction of flow (e.g. that fragment shader invocations never spawn new vertex shaders).

That being said, you are looking in the wrong part of the specification. The paragraph you are quoting "only" specifies the **logical** order. I.e. that pipeline stages are added implicitly to synchronization commands as appropriate. Logically-earlier stages are implicitly added to any source scope parameter, and logically-later stages are added to any destination stage parameter. But careful, this does not say anything about side-effects of the shaders, and it does not apply to *memory dependency*, which have to have the stage explicitly stated to work.

What you are looking for is [Shader Execution](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#shaders-execution) chapter:

> The relative execution order of invocations of different shader types is largely undefined. However, when invoking a shader whose inputs are generated from a previous pipeline stage, the shader invocations from the previous stage are guaranteed to have executed far enough to generate input values for all required inputs.